# Terminal hanging on Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

I am trying to run rails console to run model queries e.g. Post.all or User.all

However, when I try to run the console I get the following message which then hangs indefinitely:

Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)

My guess would be that this is a ruby installation error; any help and pointers appreciated.

Comment: Run Rails console then wait some time (about 2 minutes), then press Ctrl+C and provide backtrace of error. It can help to investigate problem.

Comment: are you running on windows?

Comment: I'm running Mac Yosemite

Comment: Same problem when you run `rails s` ?

Comment: No - WEBrick starts fine.

Comment: I've tried using the RubyMine IDE and the same problem with the console. Server runs ok.